# Is a Minkowski functional with respect to a non-open set still a seminorm?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $U$ be a convex balanced neighborhood of $0$ in a topological vector space $X$. The Minkowski functional can be defined as
$$\mu_U(x):=\inf \{ t>0: x\in tU  \}.$$
Is this always a seminorm, even if $U$ is not open? I was asking myself, because some authors prefer neighborhoods to be open and some not. Does it make any difference?

My guess is "No", because I have written a proof, which does not rely on $U$ being closed or open. But I am asking myself, if there is any counterexample, which might point out a mistake in my proof.

**Proof:** One can show, that $U$ is absorbent, i.e. $X=\cup_{t>0}tU$. Then for any $x\in X$ there is a $t>0$ such that $x\in tU$, which implies $\mu_U(x)<\infty$.

Moreover, since $U$ is balanced, one finds $sU\subseteq tU$ for any $s\in[0,t]$. This implies that $x\in (t+\epsilon) U$ for any $\epsilon >0$, if $\mu_U(x)=t$.

Now, let $x,y\in X$ with $\mu_U(x)=t$ and $\mu_U(y)=s$. From the above, one finds for any $\epsilon > 0$, that $\frac{x}{t+\epsilon}\in U$, $\frac{y}{s+\epsilon}\in U$ and

$$\frac{x+y}{t+s+2\epsilon}=\frac{t+\epsilon}{t+s+2\epsilon}\frac{x}{t+\epsilon}+\frac{s+\epsilon}{t+s+2\epsilon}\frac{y}{s+\epsilon}\in U,$$
since $U$ is convex, i.e. $x+y\in((t+s)+2\epsilon)U$, such that $\mu_U(x+y)\le t+s = \mu_U(x)+\mu_U(y)$.

From there, one can show, that $tU=(-t)U$ for any $t>0$ and from this that for any $\lambda\ne 0$, it holds $\{t>0: \lambda x\in tU\}=\{t>0: |\lambda| x\in tU\}$, such that $\mu_U(\lambda x)=\mu_U(|\lambda|x)=|\lambda|\mu_U(x)$.

Comment: Please include your proof, and point where you doubt it.

Comment: I do not doubt it, but still question it. One definitely, need a neighborhood of $0$ for $U$ to be absorbent and such that $\mu_U<\infty$. Balanced and convex at the mentioned places is also needed at the mentioned places in the proof.

Comment: At a later point I basically want to use these seminorms to form a separating family of seminorms, where I need to consider open $U$. (Any not necessarily open convex neighborhood of $0$ containes a convex balanced _open_ neighbordhood of $0$, though. So these can be found.) However, at this point I was asking myself, if I did a mistake on the proof above and should have defined the Minkowski functional on an _open_ set.

Comment: Your proof is correct but [can be slightly simplified](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonctionnelle_de_Minkowski#Jauge_d'un_convexe).

Comment: So, it does not depend if $U$ is _open_ or _non-open_?

Comment: No, it doesn't. You proved it and your proof is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your time and evaluation!

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Minkowski_Functional_of_Balanced_Convex_Absorbing_Set_in_Vector_Space_is_Seminorm